# Python doesn't install modules?

Tags: python, module

I can't seem to get a module installed with Python 2.7.3, or well, a lot of modules in fact. When I download the module, and then run "python setup.py install" from the folder, it looks like it installs - however, trying to import the module does not work. So, I went ahead and looked in site-packages - the only thing I found was the .egg file, which is not helpful in any way. Then, I did a search for the module in the entire folder of Python2.7, results: the .egg file and something totally unrelated. I have gotten some modules installed in the past (twill, BeautifulSoup, and a few others), some partially installed (pyglet, installed and in the folder, however running doesn't work) and then there's a whole load of modules that just don't install. They create a .egg file and that's it. Done. Nothing else. It's really annoying, so I'm wondering what could cause the issue?

The module I was trying to install was the feedparser module.

**Edit**: After doing >>>help() and then modules, it's not showing up there either.

Comment: Could you use a package manager, such as [Pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html), to help you with these issues?

Comment: also install you packages in a virtual environment.

Comment: Using pip didn't work, still only created the .egg file. I will try a virtualenv

Comment: Actually, nevermind, pip did work. I will still install virtualenv just for the sake of this happening again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pip as a module (package) manager, better that installing things manually.
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-pip-usage

Plus using virtualenv is a good practice.
http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html